# How to print a vector array?

Tags: c++, gdb

I have a vector array called `nVectors`.

```
vector<int>* nVectors[21];
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i ++) {
    nVectors[i] = generateVector(i);
}
```

I can print all the members of a single vector, but when it comes to the vector array, I still don't know how to print all the vectors in an array.

Maybe an iterator through all the member of a vector array and print using my predefined method `pvector` can solve this problem? But I don't know how to iterate in gdb.

Comment: What do you mean by 'print' to the screen or in gdb?

Comment: What's up with `generateVector()`?

Comment: In gdb.  `generateVector` method just return a pointer of vector.

Comment: Why don't you start your array indexing at 0?

Comment: Because i am doing some ACM training. Making it start from 1 can make this problem easier to comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::array<std::vector<int>*, 21> nVectors;

for(std::array<std::vector<int>*>::iterator i = nVectors.begin();
    i != nVectors.end();
    ++i)
{
    for(std::vector<int>::iterator it = (*i)->begin();
        it != (*i)->end();
        ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
}

std::cout << std::endl;
```

Or, in C++11:

```
std::vector<int>* nVectors[21];

for(auto &i : nVectors)
{
    for(auto &it : i)
    {
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
}

std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: I believe the OP means, "how can I tell gdb to print out the contents of every vector in an array of pointers to vectors?", not "how can I write C++ code to print out the contents of every vector in an array of pointers to vectors?" Also, I'm a bit tempted to -1, since your answer shows how to print a `std::array` rather than how to print an array of pointers: not very useful to someone who has an array of pointers, given that you don't even explain how to convert from one to the other . . .

Comment: Maybe to add `cout << endl` at the end of outer cycle?